# How to create a user controlled booking calender for costum post types?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently working on a website which lets users create posts for their vacation homes, and I want to enable my subscribes to control a calendar which shows when homes are rented out or unavailable.

I have created a custom post type for the vacation homes. Subscribers can post their homes on the website. But is there anyway i can integrate a calender where subscriber can mark a period in which the home is not available?

I have tried several plugins (e.g. event manager) but it seems that the subscribes in this case control the same calendar. I want a calendar that is specific to the post, and can be controlled (preferably on post editor page) in the admin area.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) or similar. . . Note that asking for recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: Ok thanks, didn't know about that. I don't really know how I would go about programming it - or rather where to start. I was thinking about writing something in PHP and MySql maybe.

Comment: What ACF does: add a meta box in the post type; add a jQuery interface for a calendar; save the data as a custom field for each post; can be a single field for the calendar or a repeatable field.

Comment: Thanks - I think adding meta boxes to my custom post type is the way to go!